# Applications of AI/ML in UX

Tags: user-behavior, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I've been tasked with looking into potential uses of AI/Machine Learning in our UX department. So far I've found AI that learns users behavior from analysing their patterns of use around the site then optimising the journey in real-time by changing the order of items in filters/burger menus etc.

There are a number of companies out there claiming all sorts of crazy conversion uplifts from these platforms but I'm skeptical.

Does anyone have any experience of this or come across any articles I can have a look into?

Answer (score 3):

There are limitless uses for AI/ML in UX.

Some examples would be:

-**Search Algorithms**
Many search algorithms use AI to improve suggestions and customize results.

-**Image/Video Recognition and Pattern Detection**
Things like people/ojbect detections are used everywhere. From auto-focus on your phone to Facebook auto-tagging your friends.

-**Smart Recommendations/Suggestions**
You see this on a lot of e-commerce sites. AI/ML can be used to display similar products of interest.

-**Customize Workflows,Preferences and Content Delivery**
Advertising companies use this. You see this everyday in targeted advertising.

-**Improve Security Features & Fraud Detection**
AI/ML can used to identify irregularities in user behavior triggering security flags and other fraud prevention/security safeguards.

-**SEO and Accessibility Enhancements**
Lots of sites use AI/ML to generate meta-date and accessibility content. Take a look at the 'alt' attribute on your Facebook profile. Facebook uses ML/AI to auto generate appropriate alt tags from your photos.

There are countless articles on all of the topics you would need to be a little more specifics than just AI applications for UX.

Comment: This is Best answer